ISC DHCP 4.4 server giving out leases, but no entries in leases file - where are they?
Running ISC DHCP Server 4.4. (I know, I know, it's EOL...there was a very good reason I uninstalled Kea-DHCP-Server and decided to go with it's predecessor ISC-DHCP-Server...though I can't recall what it was right now...)
I appear to be getting leases, but the leases file is empty.
I cannot work out where the leases are being tracked.
dhcp-lease-list shows nothing.
/var/lib/dhcp/dhcpd.leases only lists old leases and the file access time shows it hasn't been updated recently.
tcpdump -vv -n -i eth0 'udp and port 67' shows DHCP traffic as expected.
Scratching my head wondering what is going on.

Any chance you have a second dhcp server running on the system? If you stop dhcpd, are leases still being served? Do the logs from dhcpd indicate any issues?

If you have assigned addresses in /etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf, then leases are not recorded.

@DavidG. I commented out all my reservations, but still nothing. This is good to know, though.

@larsks You can't run two DHCP servers at once if they're both listening on the same interface and same port number (UDP67), because there would be a port clash. Each port can only be used by one process on one IP interface at a time.

@skeetastax that's correct! But was the result of your testing? When you disabled dhcpd, were leases still getting served? How about the logs?

@larsks If you mean another device handing out leases, I am migrating subnets one by one from the old DHCP server (FW) to this. I disable the DHCP server on each subnet and enable the DHCP Relay for each subnet to point to this new DHCP server. There is no lease on the other device (old DHCP server). For the sake of ruling it out, after disabling ISC DHCP Server, no lease is granted to client.

I get the following in the logs: 2024-06-26T17:38:28+10:00 host isc-dhcp-server[609562]: Stopping ISC DHCPv4 server: dhcpd.
2024-06-26T17:38:28+10:00 host systemd[1]: isc-dhcp-server.service: Succeeded.
2024-06-26T17:38:28+10:00 host systemd[1]: isc-dhcp-server.service: Unit process 250264 (dhcpd) remains running after unit stopped. The last of these I find odd...
